# Is JPA persistence context isolated between threads?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am aware of Hibernate 1st level cache. 
I know that it is session-scoped and I expect a session to be bound to a thread.

Since JPA is only a specification and can be backed by other providers 
my question is 
 does JPA persistence context always give the same guarantee?

E.g. will changes made in one thread

```
        Object o = entityManager.find(Object.class, id);
        o.setAttr(..);
        // not flushed
```

ever be visible in another?

Comment: Considering how much compatibility issues it would cause if that weren't the case, I'd say definitely. If you want the location in the spec where that is stated, you're going to have to read it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Within a persistence context, entities are managed and the EntityManager controls their lifecycle.

A persistence context is accessed through an EntityManager instance.

According to the documentation of Hibernate which is the most used JPA specification implementation ([Chapter 5. Transactions and Concurrency](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics) ):

> A EntityManagerFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once, usually on application startup.
>
> An EntityManager is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should be used once, for a single business process, a single unit of work, and then discarded.